# UI Image View Animations When Using ScrollView

Tags: animation, uiimage, imageview, scrollview

I am currently working on a project where I have a scroll view and four different screens. I have used a simple UIImage(named:"")!, code to put the frames of images into my imageView and animate the image.

I am having a problem where when I slide to my next screen the animation has already been completed. I do not know how to make it so that when I slide to the next screen the animation will then begin.

Here is the code for the animal animation

```
 imageView.animationDuration = 1
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1
    imageView.animationImages =

        [

            UIImage(named:"Deer_00014")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00015")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00016")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00017")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00018")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00019")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00020")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00021")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00022")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00023")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00024")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00025")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00026")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00027")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00028")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00029")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00030")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00031")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00032")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00033")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00034")!,
            UIImage(named:"Deer_00035")!,

    ]
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Deer_00035")
    imageView.startAnimating()
```

Comment: you code look okay, where have you put this code?

Comment: why are you setting image then?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line

```
self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Deer_00035")
```

Basically here you are setting the image to the ímageview' overwriting animation.